# Proof that the Fat Cantor set is not a null set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, cantor-set

To be specific, the Fat Cantor set (denoted $F$) in question here is the one obtained when removing an interval of length $\frac{1}{4}$ from $[0,1]$, an interval of length $\frac{1}{16}$ from the two intervals obtained from step 1, etc. Also, a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is denoted a null set if for each $\epsilon > 0$ there is a countable covering of $A$ by open intervals $(a_i, b_i)$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} b_i - a_i \leq \epsilon$$

My proof is as follows:

The length of the $F^c$ (i.e. the intervals removed during the construction) is given by $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^n (\frac{1}{4})^{n+1} = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16}...$$ which converges to $\frac{1}{2}$. Hence, the length of $F \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, implying that $F$ has nonzero outer measure, and so is not a null set.

Did I miss or gloss over anything? To be honest this explanation seems a little too straightforward, so any comments/hole-poking would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would avoid calling it a "zero set" since most of us do not use that phrase in this context.  Certainly "set of measure zero" or "set of Lebesgue measure zero."  Maybe "measure zero set" and even, but only when the context is really clear, "null set" but that might be rare.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I added in the definition of a zero set to make things explicit. Out of curiosity, in what other contexts does the notion of a zero set exist?

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_set , zero sets are important in several branches of geometry and topology.

Comment: I generally hear "zero set" used to mean the set of zeroes of some function, usually continuous or otherwise nice.

Comment: It is called null set instead in measure theory.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. Fat Cantor set is a nowhere dense set with positive Lebesgue measure. In measure theory, set with Lebesgue measure zero is called null set.

Answer (score 2):

There's a point that was glossed over, since you ask:

If I'm interpreting the "etc" correctly, then $K=\bigcap K_n$, where $K_n$ is the union of $2^n$ intervals of length $\delta_n$, where $\delta_0=1$ and $$\delta_{n+1}=\frac{\delta_n-4^{-(n+1)}}{2}.$$

What's missing is  a proof that $\delta_n>4^{-(n+1)}$; you need this because if not then in going from $K_n$ to $K_{n+1}$ you replace each interval by itself minus a *longer* interval.

It's clear that at each stage the "remaining intervals" are shorter than the remaining intervals in the construction of the middle-thirds set; indeed you can easily show $\delta_n>3^{-n}$ by induction.

Or if that's not enough fun you can show that in fact $$\delta_n=2^{-n-1}+2^{-2n-1}.$$ (Of course it's trivial to verify that; I hope someone does so just to check my algebra. If you're curious how one might *find* that formula: Write the recurrence as $2\delta_{n+1}-\delta_n=-4^{-(n+1)}$; now by analogy with the standard technique for first-order linear DEs write $\delta_n=2^{-n}\alpha_n$ and you get $\alpha_{n+1}-\alpha_n=$ something explicitly summable...)